# PyCharm is not able find app.yaml when pushing to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I wrote a simple pymongo code insert a few values in MongoDB instance on GAE and My app got deployed properly from Pycharm but,

I am getting the same error while running following command

**appcfg.py -A login-services-1354 -V v1 update** . on my cloud shell

The following is the error I got Usage: appcfg.py [options] update | [file, ...] appcfg.py: error: Directory '/home/seshanthnadal' does not contain configuration file app.yaml

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you see the same if you specify the full path to the app directory instead of `.`?

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is that the "directory '/home/seshanthnadal' does not contain configuration file app.yaml"...

Comment: When you say "on my cloud shell" you mean the Cloud Shell interface that is in console.cloud.google.com?

Comment: @BrettJ yes on my cloud.google.com

Comment: Which folder contains your app.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to the `appcfg update` command  is the yaml file or directory containing yaml file